# Create a CSS square with centered content, ideally using Semantic-UI

Tags: css, semantic-ui

I've got a react app and at the bottom of the page, below the rest of the content, I'd like to create a perfect square (we usually use images, but I'd like to avoid it) with a single letter or icon in the middle.

I can get it roughly working using a grid (ie 7 columns wide, 3 empty columns around the 4th). I style the middle column to be a specific color, but the text that goes inside starts to... push to the right if I make the font too large. If I use an icon, I get similar issues. Is there a good/right way to do this?

**Adding Code Sample**

Here is an example of what I'm trying to do. I'd like the content to be centered in the boxes. I'll only be showing 1 box at a time, with either a letter or Icon in it. The box would ideally be centered on the page as

[CodeSandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/semantic-ui-example-xb130?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no specific component to do this kind of thing with semantic. An easy way to do this however is to create a small react component which uses flex to center your content.

Here is an example, I modified the codesandbox you provided.

```
import React from "react";
import { Label, Icon } from "semantic-ui-react";

const Square = ({ background, color, children }) => {
  const squareStyles = {
    width: 150,
    height: 150,
    textAlign: "center",
    fontSize: 5 + "em",
    lineHeight: 1 + "em",
    display: "flex",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: `#${background}`,
    color: `#${color}`
  };

  return <div style={squareStyles}>{children}</div>;
};

const Sample = () => (
  <div>
    <Square background="21BA45" color="fff">
      G
    </Square>
    <Label>OR</Label>
    <Square background="1B1C1D">
      <Icon name="flag checkered" inverted />
    </Square>
  </div>
);

export default Sample;
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/semantic-ui-example-5636d)

Answer (score 1):

This would be much easier if you included your code and perhaps a visual. As close as I can tell, you want something like this:

```css
.icons {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  gap: 10px;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  background-color: #fab;
}

.letter {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  word-break: break-word;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="icons">
  <div>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="letter">
        A
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="letter">
        B
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="letter">
        C
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @coreyward, I've added a link to codesandbox with what I'm trying to do.